# JSTL and bindings in the stateless mode

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, jsf-stateless

An excerpt taken from a book,

> For a stateless view, the component tree cannot be dynamically
>   generated/changed (for example, JSTL and bindings are not available in
>   the stateless mode). You can't create/manipulate views dynamically.

I perfectly understand the concept of going stateless as in a `login` form.

What I don't understand is the author's point on, *JSTL and bindings are not available in the stateless mode*. Please elucidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author seems to be confused itself or overgeneralizing a bit too much.

The component tree can certainly still be dynamically generated/changed. This does not depend on stateful/stateless mode. The only difference with stateful mode is that those dynamic actions won't be remembered in JSF state, so they can't be restored in the postback.

It will in stateless mode continue to work fine if those dynamic changes are initiated by a **non**-user event during view build time, such as `@PostConstruct` of a request scoped bean referenced via `binding` attribute, or a `postAddToView` event listener method. It will simply be re-executed. If the method logic however in turn depends on some user-controlled variables/actions, such as request parameters or actions invoked during previous postbacks, or it is executed too late, such as during the `preRenderView` event, then it's not anymore guaranteed that the view will during apply request values phase of the subsequent postback become identical as it was during rendering the form to be submitted. In such case, processing the form submit may behave "unexpectedly" different as compared to a stateful view.

Comment: the author is none other than Anghel Leonard, and the abstract is taken from chapter 9 of the book "Mastering Java Server Faces 2.2"

Comment: I'll let him know :) Nonetheless, kudos for bringing exactly this under attention.